# rabbitmq-server start failed

Tags: rabbitmq, erlang, centos8

Facing issue with rabbitmq server startup. Rabbitmq-server start fails with logs -

```
noti] <0.147.0> Protocol 'inet_tcp': register/listen error: etimedout
noti] <0.147.0>
erro] <0.144.0>     supervisor: {local,net_sup}
erro] <0.144.0>     errorContext: start_error
erro] <0.144.0>     reason: {'EXIT',nodistribution}
erro] <0.144.0>     offender: [{pid,undefined},
erro] <0.144.0>                {id,net_kernel},
erro] <0.144.0>                {mfargs,{net_kernel,start_link,
erro] <0.144.0>                                    [[rabbit_prelaunch_186103@localhost,
erro] <0.144.0>                                      shortnames],
erro] <0.144.0>                                     false,net_sup_dynamic]}},
erro] <0.144.0>                {restart_type,permanent},
erro] <0.144.0>                {shutdown,2000},
erro] <0.144.0>                {child_type,worker}]
erro] <0.144.0>

BOOT FAILED
[erro] <0.131.0>
[erro] <0.131.0> BOOT FAILED
[erro] <0.131.0> ===========
[erro] <0.131.0> Exception during startup:
[erro] <0.131.0>
[erro] <0.131.0> error:{badmatch,{error,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,net_kernel,{'EXIT',nodistribution}}},{child,undefined,net_sup_dynamic,{erl_distribution,start_link,[[rabbit_prelaunch_186103@localhost,shortnames],false,net_sup_dynamic]},permanent,1000,supervisor,[erl_distribution]}}}}
[erro] <0.131.0>
[erro] <0.131.0>     rabbit_prelaunch_dist:duplicate_node_check/1, line 78
[erro] <0.131.0>     rabbit_prelaunch_dist:setup/1, line 23
[erro] <0.131.0>     rabbit_prelaunch:do_run/0, line 115
[erro] <0.131.0>     rabbit_prelaunch:run_prelaunch_first_phase/0, line 32
[erro] <0.131.0>     supervisor:do_start_child_i/3, line 385
[erro] <0.131.0>     supervisor:do_start_child/2, line 371
[erro] <0.131.0>     supervisor:-start_children/2-fun-0-/3, line 355
[erro] <0.131.0>     supervisor:children_map/4, line 1171
```

This issue is on centos and rabbitmq version is 3.9.11 / erlang 23.3.4
Already tried rebooting the system, deleting /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia files and restarting rabbitmq (no luck).
Has anyone faced this issue?

Comment: Please provide more information on configuration, `Protocol 'inet_tcp': register/listen error: etimedout` indicates that there is an error in TCP stack that prevents to bind port, but guess what it is doing is really hard. Maybe you need to check if RabbitMQ ports are not occupied by some application.